# SqlException: Server does not exist or connection refused

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, ubuntu, monodevelop

I am using c# on monodevelop on Ubuntu x64.
I am trying to use Mono.Data.Sqlite to connect to a local (localhost) database but I cant connect to it.
This is my connection string:

```
 string connsqlstring = "Server=localhost;" + 
"Database=wsep;" + "User ID=root;" + "Password=1234;" + "Pooling=false";
```

But I keep getting:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Server does not exist or connection refused.
```

I have started the server (sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start)
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, **SQLite** isn't the same thing as **MySQL**. They're different databases.

SQLite is a flat file database, the mono side of which you can read about [here](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite).

[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) has information [on the mono website](http://mono-project.com/MySQL) and that page also provides links to downloading the MySQL connector for use with your mono projects. You will want to look at these links for working with MySQL.

Comment: Ohh I feel dumb now.. Thanks for the explanation!